# User defined runtime attributes visual studio 2015

Tags: ios, xamarin

is there a way to define user defined runtime attributes in visual studio (IOs xamarin universal app template) ?

In XCode

[image]

I can't find a way how to do this in VS 2015 designer. Is it possible?